Change keybindings for quick pick separator navigation
I saw the introduction of this new feature in version 1.88: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_quick-pick-separator-navigation-keybindings
These keybindings interfere with some of my custom keybindings, and I can't seem to find the new keybinding when i search for cmd+down in Keyboard shortcuts. Is it possible to change this new keybinding?
Went to keyboard shortcuts, searched for cmd+down. Expected there to be a search result about quick pick separator navigation, but there were none.

Old Answer
Quick Picks have a couple things hardcoded and at the time of this writing, this is one of them. This specific ask is the subject of feature request 
Allow to modify hardcoded quick open keybinding shortcuts
#98479. I'm not aware of any workarounds. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
Updated Answer
Thanks to PR #211756, you can use the following commands:

quickInput.nextSeparatorWithQuickAccessFallback
quickInput.nextSeparator
quickInput.previousSeparatorWithQuickAccessFallback
quickInput.previousSeparator

Concerning the variations, I quote the following comments from the source code:

The next & previous separator commands are interesting because if we are in quick access mode, we are already holding a modifier key down.
In this case, we want that modifier key+up/down to navigate to the next/previous item, not the next/previous separator.
To handle this, we have a separate command for navigating to the next/previous separator when we are not in quick access mode.
If, however, we are in quick access mode, and you hold down an additional modifier key, we will navigate to the next/previous separator.

Not sure when this releases. Apparently as part of the April 2024 release?
